# I'm writing code for comparison of date.print First,if first one is greater (or) print Second,if second one is greater,Error if the dates are invalid

Tags: python-3.x, date, validation, compare

**How can I optimize this code**

```
def leapYear(year,year2):
    print(1)
    if (year%4==0 and year%100!=0 or year%400==0) and year2%4==0 and year2%100!=0 or year2%400==0:
        return True
    return False

def dValidation(date1,date2):
    if leapYear(date1[-1],date2[-1]):
        if date1[1]==2 or date2[1]==2:
            if date1[0]>29 or date2[0]>29:
                return False
    if date1[0]>31 or date2[0]>31 or date1[1]>12 or date2[1]>12:
        return False
    else:
        if date1[1]==2 or date2[1]==2:
            if date1[0]>28 or date2[0]>28:
                return False
        if date1[0]>31 or date2[0]>31 or date1[1]>12 or date2[1]>12:
            return False
    return True

date1=list(map(int,input().split("-")))
date2=list(map(int,input().split("-")))

if dValidation(date1,date2):
    if date1[-1]>date2[-1]:
        print("First")
    elif date2[-1]>date1[-1]:
        print("Second")
    elif date1[1]>date2[1]:
        print("First")
    elif date1[1]<date2[1]:
        print("Second")
    elif date1[0]>date2[0]:
        print("First")
    elif date1[0]<date2[0]:
        print("Second")
    else:
        print("invalid")
else:
   print("Invalid")
```

> **Input:-**
> *29-3-2018 15-4-2000*
> ** where 29-3-2018 is first date 15-4-2000 is second date**
>
> output:-First
>
> Input2:-31-6-2018
> 30-6-2018
> output:-First

*Note:-* print invalid if dates are invalid

> 29-2-2018,
> 2-3-2018

> output:-Invalid

Comment: Stack Overflow is more for questions about code where there are *specific* problems. General review of already-working code is more appropriate on Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

inputDate = input("Enter the first date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy' : ")

day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')

inputDate = input("Enter the second date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy' : ")
day2,month2,year2 = inputDate.split('/')

isValidDate = True
try :
    datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
    datetime.datetime(int(year2),int(month2),int(day2))
except ValueError :
    isValidDate = False

if(isValidDate) :
    print ("Input date is valid ..")
else :
    print ("Input date is not valid..")


# date in yyyy/mm/dd format 
d1 = datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
d2 = datetime.datetime(int(year2),int(month2),int(day2)) 
  
# Comparing the dates will return 
# either True or False 
print("d1 is greater than d2 : ", d1 > d2) 
print("d1 is less than d2 : ", d1 < d2) 
print("d1 is not equal to d2 : ", d1 != d2)
print("d1 is equal to d2 : ", d1 == d2)
```

Comment: can you explain datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day)) ?

Comment: @SantoshBurada it is used to convert the date entered from just integers to a Datetime value ( for example 26/02/2020 is just a string, and when we put int() for its values they are just numbers, but when we use datetime.datetime(), it will be converted to 2020-02-26 00:00:00 and dealt with as a datetime not string or int)

Comment: Thanks, Just know I was searched about it :)

Comment: @SantoshBurada you’re welcome, you could make the issue solved

Answer (score 0):

**The below code(@Usama K.Alobaidy) will give an answer along with the error because when he was passing dates to d1 and d2 which are Invalid it will through ValueError.
To avoid that we can pass the dl and d2 in try block**

```
import datetime

inputDate = input("Enter the first date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy' : ")

day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')

inputDate = input("Enter the second date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy' : ")
day2,month2,year2 = inputDate.split('/')

isValidDate = True
try :
    d1=datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
    d2=datetime.datetime(int(year2),int(month2),int(day2))
except ValueError :
    isValidDate=False


if(isValidDate) :

    if d1>d2:
        print("First")
    else:
        print("Second")
else :
    print ("Invalid")
```

**Thanks to @Usama K.Alobaidy for introducing DateTime package, I never used this package, But now I know its importance I will start**